# PHP: put array entries in new order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, loops, for-loop

I try to take the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 21
        [3] => 33
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 10
        [3] => 11
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [3] => 2
    )
```

)

and create a new array with it, taking the first entries of the source array. So the first array from this one would look like this:

```
 Array
(
[0] => 12
[1] => 5
[2] => 1
[3] => 2
 )
```

And the second one obviously like this:

```
 Array
(
[0] => 21
[1] => 5
[2] => 10
 )
```

I tried around with 2 for loops, it somewhat works  with

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($month_array[$i]) + 1; $i++)
{
    unset($temp_array);
    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < count($month_array); $i2++)
    {
        if (isset($month_array[$i2][$i]))
        {
            $temp_array[] = $month_array[$i2][$i];
        }
    }
}
```

But it leaves out some of the elements and if the source array is not complete, meaning only the 3rd array has a value for key 3, it also fails.
Any help ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$org_array = array(array(1 => 12,2 => 21,3 => 33),array(1 => 5,2 => 5,3 => 4),array(1 => 1,2 => 10,3 => 11),array(3 => 2),); // your original array

$new_array = array(); // the output array
foreach($org_array as $sub_org_value) { // for each sub array of your original array do this
    foreach($sub_org_value as $key => $value) { // for each entry in a sub array do this
        $new_array[$key][] = $value; // add the entry into the new_array in the right sub array
    }
}

print_r($new_array[1]); // yields 12,5,1
print_r($new_array[2]); // yields 21,5,10
print_r($new_array[3]); // yields 33,4,11,2
```

Afterwards you have an array `$new_array` that contains three arrays. The first sub array has all 1 values, the second sub array has all 2 values and the third sub array has all 3 values.